# Rake test error - ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, activerecord, rake-test

Everytime I do rake test i get 12 errors all with the same error

8) Error:
ProductTest#test_image_url:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

9) Error:
ProductTest#test_product_attributes_must_not_be_empty:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

10) Error:
ProductTest#test_product_is_not_valid_without_a_unique_title:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

11) Error:
ProductTest#test_product_is_not_valid_without_a_unique_title_-_i18n:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

12) Error:
ProductTest#test_product_price_must_be_positive:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

With the first line being:

```
syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
  post :create, product_id: products (:ruby).id
```

Here is my yaml file

```
one:
title: MyString
description: MyText
image_url: MyString
price: 9.99

two:
title: MyString
description: MyText
image_url: MyString
price: 9.99

ruby: 
title: "Programming Ruby 1.9"
description: "Ruby is the fastest growing and most exciting dynamic
language out there. If you need to get working programs
delivered fast, you should add Ruby to your toolbox."
price: 49.50
image_url: "ruby.png"
```

and the appropriate test files

```
require 'test_helper'

class LineItemsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @line_item = line_items(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:line_items)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create line_item" do
    assert_difference('LineItem.count') do
       post :create, product_id: products (:ruby).id
    end

    assert_redirected_to cart_path(assigns(:line_item).cart)
  end

  test "should show line_item" do
    get :show, id: @line_item
    assert_response :success
  end

   test "should get edit" do
   get :edit, id: @line_item
    assert_response :success
  end

   test "should update line_item" do
   patch :update, id: @line_item, line_item: { cart_id: @line_item.cart_id, product_id:         @line_item.product_id }
    assert_redirected_to line_item_path(assigns(:line_item))
  end

   test "should destroy line_item" do
    assert_difference('LineItem.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @line_item
    end

     assert_redirected_to line_items_path
  end
 end
```

and these are the errors for this file

1) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_create_cart:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

2) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_destroy_cart:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

3) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

4) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

5) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_get_new:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

6) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_show_cart:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

7) Error:
CartsControllerTest#test_should_update_cart:
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

```
 require 'test_helper'

 class CartsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
  @cart = carts(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
  get :index
  assert_response :success
  assert_not_nil assigns(:carts)
  end

  test "should get new" do
  get :new
  assert_response :success
  end

   test "should create cart" do
   assert_difference('Cart.count') do
   post :create, cart: {  }
  end

  assert_redirected_to cart_path(assigns(:cart))
  end

  test "should show cart" do
  get :show, id: @cart
  assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
  get :edit, id: @cart
  assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update cart" do
  patch :update, id: @cart, cart: {  }
  assert_redirected_to cart_path(assigns(:cart))
  end

  test "should destroy cart" do
  assert_difference('Cart.count', -1) do
  delete :destroy, id: @cart
  end

assert_redirected_to carts_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6):

`products` is a method that reads the contents of the fixture file. Mind the space between the name of the method and the arguments. Try the following:

```
post(:create, product_id: products(:ruby).id)
```

YAML's syntax is space-delimited based on indentation. Make sure the attributes of an entry are indented properly, e.g.:

```
ruby:
  title: "Programming Ruby 1.9"
  description: "Ruby is the fastest growing and most exciting dynamic
  language out there. If you need to get working programs
  delivered fast, you should add Ruby to your toolbox."
  price: 49.50
  image_url: "ruby.png"
```